# Issue with mouse clicking a rectangle in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, drawing, mouse

So, I'm attempting to create a grid on the screen, and to do so, I've implemented a multidimensional array of Rectangles.

When the program starts, I use a for loop to increase the x and y coordinates to form the grid.

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++) {
            recArray[x, y] = new Rectangle(y * 50, x * 50, 100, 100);
        }

        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

My issue is trying to figure out when the user has clicked on a rectangle, and furthermore, which rectangle in the array that he/she has clicked on. As I will change the border to red when given the correct rectangle.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and here is my code so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Quoridor {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

        private Pen pen = Pens.Black;

        Rectangle[,] recArray = new Rectangle[12, 12];

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++) {
                    recArray[x, y] = new Rectangle(y * 50, x * 50, 100, 100);
                }

                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++) {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, recArray[x, y]);

                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Point cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

            Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm making this into a real game, with classes and all. But keep in mind, this is my second month programming, so don't be harsh ^_^

Comment: You will need to sink the MouseClick event and get the current x and y coordinates. Use this to lookup in your list of rectangles which rectangle has been hit. I cant remember exactly but i think you need to convert the coordinates from screen to window or vice versa, to ensure you get the correct offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a couple of pointers:

- You are storing your calculated y coordinate as the x position of your rectangle and vice versa. Switch the first two arguments of the Rectangle constructor to resolve this.
- Use the [MouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of the Click event. The former provides you with a `MouseEventArgs` that contains the coordinate of the click relative to your `Form`.
- Your rectangles are currently overlapping, since they are 100 x 100 but are positioned 50 pixels apart. This appears to be unintended (as a click would then usually land on 2 rectangles). This is also why your grid appears to be 13x13 instead of 12x12. To resolve this, pass 50 instead of 100 as the width and height of your `Rectangle`s.

You could then determine the clicked `Rectangle` as follows:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle clickedRectangle = FindClickedRectangle(e.Location);
    if (!clickedRectangle.IsEmpty)
        Console.WriteLine("X: {0} Y: {1}", clickedRectangle.X, clickedRectangle.Y);
}

private Rectangle FindClickedRectangle(Point point)
{
    // Calculate the x and y indices in the grid the user clicked
    int x = point.X / 50;
    int y = point.Y / 50;

    // Check if the x and y indices are valid
    if (x < recArray.GetLength(0) && y < recArray.GetLength(1))
        return recArray[x, y];

    return Rectangle.Empty;
}
```

Notice that I determine the clicked rectangle using a straightforward calculation, which is possible because your rectangles are positioned in a grid. If you intend to depart from the grid layout, looping over all rectangles and hit testing them using [Rectangle.Contains(Point)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t27w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an alternative solution.